# Should I use only one single module in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I want to know what're the drawbacks of declaring and using ONLLY ONE module in my SPA?

Does it reduce testability?

Does it impact the performance?

Does it make code less readable or maintainable?

**assuming that:**

1. It is single page application
2. I don't share any block of code to another application
3. I use browserify to pack all files into one big .js file.
4. Even if I don't pack all js into one bundle file, isn't it true that all sub-mobules will be eventually depended by the root module? And therefore downloaded from server at the very beginning?